# Vim errorformat string to show message in QuickFix removing part of it

Tags: vim, errorformat, vim-quickfix

I'm writing an `errorformat` string, and it works for the most part. My problem is that I have lines like this as the `makeprg` output:

```
Some text I want to show in the QuickFix window^M
```

Yes, the line ends with an spurious `^M` character I want to remove. So, what I want in my QuickFix window is this, without the `^M` character:

```
|| Some text I want to show in the QuickFix window
```

but I have this instead:

```
|| Some text I want to show in the QuickFix window^M
```

So far, this is the relevant part of my `errorformat`:

```
set errorformat=%+GSome text%m
```

I've tested, without success, something like this:

```
set errorformat=%+GSome text%m%-G^M%.%#
```

but it throws an error (not from the `^M` which is a literal control-M char, not a caret followed by an M).

Obviously the solution is not using `%G` but I am at a loss here.

How can I remove the line ending character from the line here? And also, removing the initial `||` would be a plus, but I think it's impossible to do in Vim.

Thanks in advance!

**Edited to make clearer how the input text looks**

Comment: It's impossible to write/discuss an `efm` without knowing how the input text looks.

Comment: Sorry, @romainl, my bad. The text actually looks like the first QuickFix line I showed, I'll modify the question to make that clear. Thanks for pointing this, I thought that it was easy to infer from the question text but obviously I was wrong ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turns out I found a solution, probably not very good but it works, using trial and error.

```
set errorformat=%\\(Some Text%*[^.]).%\\)%\\@=%m
```

That is, the solution is using the `Vim` pattern (regex) expressions within `errorformat`, which has a quite arcane look but works, together with `%*` to match unknown text on the rest of the line

The solution uses `\@=`, a zero-width match, and requires some kind of terminator for the line, which appears **before** the `^M` character I want to ignore, and some kind of text appearing somewhere on the line to match that line and not others.

Probably there is a much better solution but this is the best I could do myself.